# When dynamically generating a ListBox with WPF I cannot seem to make data binding work correctly

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding

I am new to WPF and the MVVM design philosophy

I want to have a `View` (a `UserControl`), that is part of a window, this view should load a list of items from a database (MongoDB) in a `ListBox` and show them to the user.

The `Window1.xaml`

```
<Window xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:MyApp.MVVM.Views"
        ...>
    <Grid>
        <controls:UserControl1/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The `UserControl1.xaml`

```
<UserControl xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:MyApp.MVVM.ViewModels"
             ...>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.Resources>
            <vm:MyViewModel x:Key="DatabaseResource"/>
        </Grid.Resources>
        <Grid.DataContext>
            <Binding Source="{StaticResource DatabaseResource}"/>
        </Grid.DataContext>

    <ListBox Name="MyItemList"
        SelectionMode="Single"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyList}"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

The `UserControl1.xaml.cs` code-behind is completely untouched as generated by VS and only contains a constructor with `InitializeComponent()`

And the `MyViewModel.cs` looks something like this:

```
namespace MyApp.MVVM.ViewModels
{
    class MyViewModel
    {
        public ObservableCollection<string> MyList;
        
        public MyViewModel()
        {
            
            MongoClient client = new MongoClient("connection string");
            MyList = new ObservableCollection<string>(MyMethod(client));
        }

        private List<string> MyMethod(MongoClient client)
        {
            // Logic that queries the database
            IMongoDatabase db = client.GetDatabase("MyDatabase");
            IMongoCollection<MyItemModel> collection = db.GetCollection<MyItemModel>("MyCollection");
            var filter = Builder<MyItemModel>.Filter.Eq( ...query... );
            var res = collection.Find(filter);
            // More logic that takes res and isolates some of its contents it into a List<string>
        }
    }
}
```

Having done this, I would expect an instance of `MyViewModel` to be bound to `MyItemList` (specifically, `MyList` to be bound to the `ItemsSource` property) allowing it to display the items I have queried from my database.

I can confirm through debugging that the query logic is correct and provides the code with the expected results (a normal and non-empty `List<string>`). I have observed (through the debugger) the observable `MyList` get populated. However, once `Window1` appears on the screen, the `ItemBox` from `UserControl1` appears simply as an empty line with no items, despite having a `DataContext` with all the required contents.

The debugger also throws the following error that I cannot find the reason for, despite my searching of similar questions by others.

> System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'MyList' property not found on 'object' ''MyViewModel' (HashCode=4606985)'. BindingExpression:Path=MyList; DataItem='MyViewModel' (HashCode=4606985); target element is 'ListBox' (Name='MyItemList'); target property is 'ItemsSource' (type 'IEnumerable')

This error also appears on the debugger as a XAML Binding Failure entry. Nevertheless, the `DataContext` of `UserControl1` seems to correctly contain `MyList` full with its intended contents.

Comment: `MyList` is a field not a property ... binding can only work with properties try the followings `public ObservableCollection<string> MyList {get;}`

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding a getter to MyList:

```
public ObservableCollection<string> MyList { get; }
```